# How to install clonezilla on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Live CD. "E: Unable to locate package clonezilla"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, clonezilla, livecd

Normally I'd just use the clonezilla ISO and be done with it, but connecting to wifi with the command line only seemed far more trouble than it was worth. To avoid that, I decided to run clonezilla through a live CD with a GUI, and Ubuntu seemed an easy enough choice. First, I'd need to install clonezilla, and this is where I ran into an issue.

Running `sudo apt update; sudo apt install clonezilla` after booting into Ubuntu 22.04 gave the error

`E: Unable to locate package clonezilla`

But this doesn't happen on a full install, and the package [clearly exists](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/clonezilla), is available for 22.04, and is called `clonezilla`. For some reason [searching google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22E:+Unable+to+locate+package+clonezilla%22) for the error message returned nothing.

Answer (score 3):

It turned out to be a quick fix. Clonezilla is part of the universe repository, which is disabled by default on the live CD. To enable it, I just searched for "Software & Updates" in the activities view and clicked the blue app icon. [image: text]

I then enabled the checkbox next to "Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe)" and ran `sudo apt update; sudo apt install clonezilla`. Which worked no problems. Hopefully someone else finds this useful.